# Mysql count matches for each row and show result order by relevance

Tags: mysql, count, relevance

I want to show result in order that rows have more matches should come on top.

Like if i search for keyword 'abc' in *title* and *content*, then it count the total matches for 'abc' in title and content for each row.

Suppose it found

- 3 matches in 1st row,
- 5 matches in 2nd row,
- 2 matches in 3rd row

Then result will show 5 matches row first, after
   that 3 matches row, and so on in DESC order

I used this query but it didn't sort correct result.

```
SELECT title, MATCH(title, content) AGAINST ('>("abc def") (abc def) <(abc* def*)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
FROM articles_template
WHERE 1=1
      AND MATCH(title, content) AGAINST ('>("abc def") (abc def) <(abc* def*)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
      AND date BETWEEN '2015-02-18 00:00:00' AND '2016-02-18 00:00:00'
ORDER BY relevance DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Fulltext seraches do take number of occurances into account, but lot of other things as well. However, if fulltext searches do not produce the expected outcome, then you need to look for alternative solutions, such as sphynx to achieve what you want.

Answer (score -1):

`select count(title) as count from table_name group by title order by count`

Comment: thanks man for response, I already try this. count will not work here

Comment: As i have to match multiple words and these words can be anywhere in content

Comment: Do you have any other solution